How to sort worksheets except first sheet
I came across the code, Sub Sort_Active_Book(), which works great but I want to be able to adapt it so that the first sheet in my workbook named TOC is not sorted.  Thanks is advance.
Sub Sort_Active_Book()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim iAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
'
'
   iAnswer = MsgBox("Sort Sheets in Ascending Order?" & Chr(10) _
     & "Clicking No will sort in Descending Order", _
     vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Sort Worksheets")
   For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
      For j = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
'
' If the answer is Yes, then sort in ascending order.
'
         If iAnswer = vbYes Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) > UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
'
' If the answer is No, then sort in descending order.
'
         ElseIf iAnswer = vbNo Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) < UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
         End If
      Next j
   Next i
End Sub


If it is always the first sheet to be excluded from sort then change in the code:
For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
      For j = 2 To Sheets.Count - 1


You need to add an if statement that check that the sheet's name is not TOC. You code becomes:
Sub Sort_Active_Book()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim iAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
'
'
   iAnswer = MsgBox("Sort Sheets in Ascending Order?" & Chr(10) _
     & "Clicking No will sort in Descending Order", _
     vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Sort Worksheets")
   For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
      For j = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
'
' If the answer is Yes, then sort in ascending order.
'
        If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) <> "TOC" Then
            If iAnswer = vbYes Then
'
'Check the sheet's name if it not TOC
'
           
                If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) > UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
                    Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
                End If
'
' If the answer is No, then sort in descending order.
'
            ElseIf iAnswer = vbNo Then
                If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) < UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
                    Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
                End If
            End If
         End If
      Next j
   Next i
End Sub

